# Will upgrading my secondary router improve Wi-Fi speed?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, moonlight, nvidia-gamestream

I have an issue with the Wi-Fi signal in my room from my primary router which is in the living room. So I laid down an ethernet cable from the living room to my room and a mate of mine gave me an old router he had lying around. I use it in AP mode and I have my desktop PC connected it through ethernet.

- Primary router ethernet speed - 95 Mbps.
- Primary router Wi-Fi speed - 70 Mbps
- Secondary router ethernet speed - 90 Mbps.
- Secondary router Wi-Fi speed - ranges between 30 Mbps and 10 Mbps.

Both routers are 2.4 GHz
I have frequent lag with connection like YouTube, web browsing getting stuck. I stream games locally to my phone using moonlight, it works well with my primary router but gets stuck and crashes when connected to the secondary one.

This is the only router I found that is within my budget:
https://prolink2u.com/product/prc3801/

If I upgrade the secondary router with this. Will it improve my speeds and consistency?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is reliable - which I can't advise on - based on its specs it should improve your performance if you can use it in the 5gig band.    (Indeed I wonder if the problem with your secondary router is because its in the 2.4 gig band - either on a congested channel or its interfering with the main router or both. )

I do comment that that router is not in the dd-wrt database, which should throw up warnings, and the (lone) 3 star review on amazon.sg.  Its mediocrity is mirrored in other places on the web - so I would not expect it to be amazing.

Comment: Have you looked around for a decent second hand router like an ASUS RT-AC68U or similar ?  These are available for around the US$50 mark and are well reputed.  Better yet, they can be flashed with dd-wrt which gives them a lot of functionality, and more importantly - stability.

Comment: I agree that the router isn't amazing. The prices of everything has skyrocketed thanks to economic crisis in the country. This router itself has doubled in price over the last 3 months. 
I'm not looking for high quality 4k streaming or anything. If it can give me a consistent speed of at least 40 Mbps I'm happy.
I have set the main router to channel 1 and the secondary one to channel 11 and there are only 3 other networks in the area. I live in a very residential zone.
@davidgo Unfortunately there is a proper second hand market in my country.

Comment: What model is your second router?